# Expressão regular para validar uma senha com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

As senhas devem conter pelo menos 5 palavras(palavra = 1 ou mais letras), cada uma separada por um hífen, um espaço,um ponto, uma vírgula ou um underscore. Exemplo: a-b-b-c-d-d

OU

As senhas devem ter pelo menos  8 caracteres e conter pelo menos uma letra maiúscula, minúscula, dígitos e pontuação ( "!@#$%<^&*?").

Para o primeiro, eu tentei:

```
r"[\w.-\s,_]{4,}\w{1,}"
```

Para o segundo caso, eu tentei:

```
r"\w+\d+[!@#\$<>&\*\?]+[\w\d!@#\$<>&\*\?]{5,}"
```

---

```
import re

sentence = "test%#"

pattern = r""

print(f" match: {re.findall(pattern, sentence)}")
```

Alguma ideia?

Comment: "pelo menos caracteres" - acho que faltou falar a quantidade, né? :-) De qualquer forma, o que é uma "palavra"? Se for `@-123,abc $@,xy`, é uma senha válida? Pois as "palavras" seriam "@", "123", "abc", "$@" e "xy" (e estão separadas pelos caracteres indicados). É isso? Então a senha do seu exemplo (test%#) é inválida, certo?

Comment: @hkotsubo : acabei de editar -> pelo menos 8 caracteres

Comment: @hkotsubo Para o primeiro, um exemplo de senha valida: a-b-c-.d.e

Comment: `a-b-c-.d.e` não me parece válida, pois vc disse que tb deve ter **pelo menos uma** letra maiúscula, um dígito, e pontuação...

Comment: @hkotsubo  sao 2 tipos diferentes de senhas, ou seja, sao 2 regex diferentes!

Comment: Mas no primeiro caso, as "palavras" só tem letras? Ou podem ter outras coisas?

Comment: "5 palavras, cada uma separada por um hífen..." e "devem ter pelo menos 8 caracteres""são condições mutuamente exclusiva. O minimo no caso seriam 9 caracteres, 5 glifos e 4 espaçadores.

Comment: @hkotsubo     " palavra" = 1 ou mais letras

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para o primeiro caso, usar `\w` **não serve**, porque este atalho também considera dígitos e o caractere `_`, e como você quer que o `_` seja um dos separadores, então ele não pode fazer parte da palavra.

Supondo que não pode ter caracteres acentuados, uma forma de considerar a "palavra" é `[a-zA-Z]+` (o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` indica "uma ou mais ocorrências").

Só que isso pega apenas uma palavra. Depois temos que ter a sequência "separador + palavra", e ela deve se repetir pelo menos 4 vezes (assim teremos pelo menos 5 palavras separadas pelos caracteres indicados).

Para o separador, basta usar `[- .,_]`. Depois, basta colocar a mesma definição de "palavra" depois, e fazer esta sequência se repetir no mínimo 4 vezes. Ou seja, `([- .,_][a-zA-Z]+){4,}`.

Juntando tudo, fica `[a-zA-Z]+([- .,_][a-zA-Z]+){4,}`.

Repare que nesse caso eu não preciso colocar o requisito de no mínimo 8 caracteres. Pois se tiver pelo menos 5 palavras (com pelo menos 1 caractere) mais os 4 separadores, já vai ter mais de 8 caracteres.

---

Para o segundo caso (verificar os caracteres obrigatórios), usamos [*lookaheads*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), que servem para ver se algo existe à frente. Por exemplo, para ver se existe pelo menos um dígito, usamos `(?=.*[0-9])`. O truque é que o *lookehead* só verifica se algo existe, mas depois ele volta para onde estava e continua verificando o restante da regex. Assim garantimos que, depois de verificar se tem um dígito, ela volta e verifica o restante da expressão (ou seja, se tem letra, etc).

Para cada tipo de caractere obrigatório usamos um *lookahead*, então a regex fica essa coisa monstruosa:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%<^&*?])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%<^&*?]{8,}$
```

Cada *lookahead* verifica se um tipo de caractere existe, e depois a regex verifica se tem pelo menos 8 dos caracteres indicados.

Também usei os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que indicam respectivamente o início e fim da string, assim eu garanto que ela só tem o que a regex indica (nem um caractere a mais, nem a menos).

Como a regex pode ser uma coisa ou outra, usamos `|` para indicar que pode ser uma ou outra. Não fica nada "bonito":

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'^(((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%<^&*?])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%<^&*?]{8,})|([a-zA-Z]+([- .,_][a-zA-Z]+){4,}))$')

for senha in ['a.b.c.d.e', 'A.b-c @1_xyz', 'a.b.c', 'Abc123@!&']:
    print(f'{senha} = {"válida" if r.match(senha) else "inválida"}')
```

A saída do código acima é:

```
a.b.c.d.e = válida
A.b-c @1_xyz = inválida
a.b.c = inválida
Abc123@!& = válida
```

---

Claro que você também pode usar duas regex separadas e verificar se a senha corresponde a uma ou outra:

```
def valida(senha):
    return re.match(r'^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%<^&*?])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%<^&*?]{8,}$', senha) \
           or re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z]+([- .,_][a-zA-Z]+){4,}$', senha)

for senha in ['a.b.c.d.e', 'A.b-c @1_xyz', 'a.b.c', 'Abc123@!&']:
    print(f'{senha} = {"válida" if valida(senha) else "inválida"}')
```

Se quiser, também pode trocar as condições dos *lookaheads* por regex separadas:

```
def valida(senha):
    return (re.search(r'[0-9]', senha) and \
            re.search(r'[a-z]', senha) and \
            re.search(r'[A-Z]', senha) and \
            re.search(r'[!@#$%<^&*?]', senha) and \
            re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%<^&*?]{8,}$', senha)) \
           or re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z]+([- .,_][a-zA-Z]+){4,}$', senha)
```

A primeira regex verifica se tem um dígito, a segunda verifica se tem uma letra minúscula, etc (usei `search` para [verificar em qualquer posição da string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match), pois `match` só faz a busca a partir do início). A quinta verifica se tem pelo menos 8 dos caracteres indicados (aqui tanto faz usar `match` ou `search`, já que o `^` força a regex a procurar do início da string).

Answer (score -1):

Para cada caso, tem um Regex específico. Acompanhe as sintaxes de cada Regex. No caso do segundo caso, *lookaheads* são a solução ideal, pois eles verificam o padrão antes de dar *match*

As senhas devem conter pelo menos 5 palavras(palavra = 1 ou mais letras), cada uma separada por um hífen, um espaço,um ponto, uma vírgula ou um underscore. Exemplo: a-b-b-c-d-d

```
re.sub(r'\b'{4, }, '-', variavel_string)
```

As senhas devem ter pelo menos 8 caracteres e conter pelo menos uma letra maiúscula, minúscula, dígitos e pontuação ( "!@#$%<^&*?")

```
re.match('r(^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@$#%&çÇ`\'^~]).{8,}$)')
```

Comment: A primeira regex não faz sentido porque `sub` serve para substituir trechos da string, e não pra encontrar matches. Aliás, da forma que está, o código sequer executa, [veja](https://ideone.com/5VLSF6). E mesmo se corrigir esse código, usar `\b{4, }` não faz sentido porque `\b` marca apenas uma posição da string que possui um caractere alfanumérico antes e um não alfanumérico depois, e vc está buscando por 4 posições consecutivas que sejam assim, o que não valida nada. Na prática, isso só retorna as senhas sem alterações e não valida nada: https://ideone.com/NXLNIo

Comment: Na verdade é pior, por causa do espaço depois da vírgula, a regex procura pelo texto  `{4, }` e substitui ele por  hífen: https://ideone.com/X5FsFw - Ou seja, está **muito** longe de validar qualquer coisa... E se remover o espaço dá erro porque o `\b` não é quantificável: https://ideone.com/jSNQZZ