# Como verificar se tem número na senha em Python?

Tags: python

Preciso de ajuda quanto a uma questão sobre strings em Python. O enunciado diz o seguinte:

Escreva um programa para ler uma senha e verificar se a mesma contém as exigências de segurança: Pelo menos um caractere maiúsculo e um minúsculo, além de conter números e letras, bem como contenha no mínimo 6 e no máximo 10 caracteres.

No código que eu fiz, tava tudo certo, até o momento que tinha que verificar se tinha números na senha. O código é esse:

```
while True:
  senha = input('Digite sua senha: ')
  list(senha)
  if len(senha) < 6:
    print('Deve conter no mínimo 6 caracteres.')
  elif len(senha) > 10:
    print('Deve conter no máximo 10 caracteres.')
  else:
    if any(x.isupper() for x in senha):
      print('Deve conter pelo menos uma letra minúscula.')
    elif any(x.islower() for x in senha):
      print('Deve conter pelo menos uma letra maiúscula.')
    elif any(x.isdigit() == False for x in senha):
      print('Deve conter pelo menos um número.')
    else:
      break
    
print('Senha válida.')
```

No output tentei várias situações possíveis, pra testar todas as exigências de segurança, mas aí deu problema na última exigência que está no código. O resultado no output deu isso:

```
Digite sua senha: ash
Deve conter no mínimo 6 caracteres.
Digite sua senha: Charlie12345
Deve conter no máximo 10 caracteres.
Digite sua senha: r4gn4rok
Deve conter pelo menos uma letra maiúscula.
Digite sua senha: H41LM4RY
Deve conter pelo menos uma letra minúscula.
Digite sua senha: Brazuka
Deve conter pelo menos uma letra minúscula.
```

OBS.: Na última linha deveria ter dado um aviso de que a senha deve conter pelo menos um número, mas ao invés disso, aparece essa mensagem.

Como eu faço pra resolver isso? Poderiam me ajudar nesse código?

Comment: acredito que a abordagem ideal seria utilizar RegEx, para cada condição um regex e ver se ele passa no teste

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/443332/112052

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias formas de poder fazer essas checagens de forma mais elegante, segura e performática, porém vou focar simplesmente em explicar o por que o seu código não funcionou pra chegar se existe números na senha.

O motivo principal é que a forma que você está usando a função `any()` está invertida. Ela está invertida para todas as condições, e por isso está parando o seu código na primeira condição "verificar se tem pelo menos uma letra maiúscula".

```
if any(x.isupper() for x in senha):
    print('Deve conter pelo menos uma letra minúscula.')
```

Primeiramente, como o `any()` funciona:

- se qualquer item da lista for verdadeiro, o any retorna `True`
- se TODOS os itens da lista forem falsos, o any retorna `False`

Então, basicamente, o seu `elif` pode ser lido da seguinte como "se qualquer item da minha lista for uma letra maiúscula, retorna a mensagem de que deve conter pelo menos um uma letra minúscula". Enquanto o que você quer é algo como "se NENHUM item da minha lista for uma letra maiúscula, retorna a mensagem de que deve conter uma letra maiúscula".

A forma de corrigir isso no código atual é negando a condição e invertendo a mensagem.

```
if not any(x.isupper() for x in senha):
  print('Deve conter pelo menos uma letra maiúscula.')
```

Isso tem que ser feito pra todas as condições usando o `any()`.